# Adding a new URL (domain) to a page

Tags: seo, google-search, domain-name

A friend of mine has opened a local business and not knowing what to do choose a URL with the name of her company (which is a playword). The chosen name is quite bad for google ranking because not meaningful: not indicating the nature of business nor the location (city).

I would like her to buy two new domains:
businessname-business-type-city.com
businessnamebusinesstypecity.com

is that still ok with google? I was doing that some years ago and ranked first on the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get as many domain names as you want, and set  up the DNS to point to the ip of playword. But  don't think it would be worth it, and no guarantee it would generate more hits.. Google search take location in consideration, so you're probably best of branding playword, and generate buzz in other ways; social media, flyers, many Google ads, and sponsored posts on Facebook

And be sure to have good semantics on your page

Answer (score 1):

If the domain name is the name  of the business then it is meaningful. Value of keywords in domain names has been diminished in recent times. Market the business, not the domain name. (And google local business results will help)